# Undo is not working in excel add in with in the used range

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I have an excel add-in to collect the data and store it on the server.

But if I try to undo any cell value within the excel used range it is not working, but in that same sheet if enter anything in other cells and try to undo it is working fine.

Could anyone please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I try to get the range of excel sheet then it is not working.

If I did not use Range.UsedRange then undo seems working fine for me.

I think after Range.UsedRange control will not get back to edited cell.